# Using AspectJ to recognize method calls

Tags: maven, osgi, aspectj, equinox

I like to use AspectJ to recognize when a certain method is called within another OSGi bundle I don't have the source code for. Therefore, I build an aspect-bundle. For learning puposes the other bundle is implemented by a sample bundle which simply implements a "sayHello" method. The aspect-bundle is now supposed to recognize whenever this method is called.

Here is what I have so far:

**normal bundle**

> *HelloWorld.java*

```
    package com.mango.sample.helloworld;

    public class HelloWorld {
        public void sayHello() {
            System.out.println("Hello world");
        }
    }
```

> *Activator.java*

```
    package com.mango.sample.helloworld;

    import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
    import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

    public class Activator implements BundleActivator {
        private static BundleContext context;

        public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
            Activator.context = bundleContext;
            HelloWorld test = new HelloWorld();
            test.sayHello();
        }

        public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
            Activator.context = null;
        }
    }
```

> *pom.xml*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>com.mango.sample</groupId>
      <artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
      <version>0.1</version>
      <packaging>bundle</packaging>
      <name>helloworld</name>

      <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.0.4</maven>
      </prerequisites>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
          <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
          <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>

      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
              <instructions>
                <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
                <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                <Bundle-Name>${project.name}</Bundle-Name>
                <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                <Bundle-Activator>com.mango.sample.helloworld.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
              </instructions>
              <manifestLocation>${project.basedir}/META-INF</manifestLocation>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </project>
```

**aspect-bundle**

> *Activator.java*

```
    package com.mango.sample.helloworldj;
    import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
    import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

    public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

        private static BundleContext context;
        public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
            Activator.context = bundleContext;
        }
        public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
            Activator.context = null;
        }
    }
```

> *AspectJTest.aj*

```
    package com.mango.sample.helloworldj;
    public aspect AspectJTest {
        before() : execution(* *.sayHello()) {
            System.out.println("Before execution sum");
        }
    }
```

> *pom.xml*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>com.mango.sample</groupId>
      <artifactId>helloworldj</artifactId>
      <version>0.1</version>
      <packaging>bundle</packaging>
      <name>helloworldj</name>

      <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.0.4</maven>
      </prerequisites>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
          <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
          <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
          <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
          <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>

      <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.7</source>
              <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
              <instructions>
                <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
                <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                <Bundle-Name>${project.name}</Bundle-Name>
                <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                <Bundle-Activator>com.mango.sample.helloworldj.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                <Export-Package>com.mango.sample.helloworldj;aspects=AspectJTest</Export-Package>
              </instructions>
              <manifestLocation>${project.basedir}/META-INF</manifestLocation>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>  
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>  
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
            <version>1.3</version>  
            <configuration>  
              <complianceLevel>1.5</complianceLevel>  
            </configuration>  
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>  
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </project>
```

After compiling, I start equinox (separately from eclipse)

> *configuration/config.ini*

```
    osgi.framework.extensions=org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook_1.0.200.I20130319-1000.jar
    osgi.bundles=\
        reference\:file\:../lib/org.apache.felix.fileinstall-3.1.6.jar@1:start,\
        reference\:file\:../lib/org.eclipse.osgi.services-3.3.100.v20120522-1822@2:start,\
        reference\:file\:../lib/org.eclipse.equinox.console-1.0.0.v20120522-1841.jar@start,\
        reference\:file\:../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar@1:start,\
        reference\:file\:../lib/logback-classic-1.0.9.jar@1:start,\
        reference\:file\:../lib/logback-core-1.0.9.jar@1:start,\
        reference\:file\:../lib/org.aspectj.runtime_1.7.3.20130613144500-a.jar@2:start
```

and the options:

```
     -Daj.weaving.verbose=true
     -Dorg.aspectj.weaver.showWeaveInfo=true
     -Dorg.aspectj.osgi.verbose=true
```

Then, I install and start the aspect bundle and the other bundle afterwards. After starting the HelloWorld bundle, I expected something like this

```
    Before execution
    Hello world
```

But I got only `Hello world`. I guess there is going something wrong with weaving the aspects into the helloworld bundle. Is there something missing in the pom.xml files?

How can I solve it?

Comment: Currently I have the same problem but with other OSGI engine (Apache Felix)
Could you provide me more information about your solution If you solved this problem?